# SQL invalid datatype time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table in Oracle SQL*Plus and it won't take the datatype `time`, but has no problem taking the datatype `date`.

```
drop table order;
create table orders (
order_id char(4) not null,
order_date date,
order_time time, -- invalid datatype
cash_time char(3),
primary key(order_id)
);
```

That's weird... why is that?  How can I fix it, or are there alternatives to using `time`?

Comment: look here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm

Comment: There is no `TIME` type in Oracle. [This was a pretty decent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13187624/1454048) from a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle there is no datatype as TIME. You can use [TIMESTAMP or DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm). So I think you need to change `TIME` to `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` and things will work for you.

I think you are getting confused with this [TIME](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj21908.html) datatype.

Comment: Well, not really. `TIMESTAMP` is really just `DATE` + fractional seconds. Unless the user has a need for fractional seconds, using just the time portion of `DATE` should work.

Comment: @admdrew:- Yes I agree but I just wanted to tell to OP that TIME is not the datatype which he is looking for. Definetely there are options which he can look for

Comment: I `-1`'d this. I see what you're saying, and I agree it's important to point out what you did to the poster, but I don't agree that it's really the best answer to the question. As I put in a comment to the question, I would consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13187624/1454048) to be a better/more constructive answer.

Comment: @admdrew:- Updated my answer. Does that make it better?

Comment: Yeah! (#stackoverflowwantsmorelettersbeforeicanaddthiscomment)

Answer (score 0):

I quickly looked at the orcle datatype [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm) and didn't see a time datatype and i think it's the problem.
why you don't use the date datatype as a single field instead of creating two field for date and time.